# Trim Not Removing Multiple White Spaces

Tags: c#, string, replace, trim, removing-whitespace

I have the following very simple example;

```
 string MyString = "Egyptian Soccer/Egyptian Premier/Fixtures 20 January  /El Shorta v El Geish";

 string[] description = MyString.Split('/');

 description.Select(s => s.Trim());
```

However the string value of 'Fixtures 20 January  ', is not having the whitespaces removed at the end.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reassign the result of the Select operation

```
string MyString = "Egyptian Soccer/Egyptian Premier/Fixtures 20 January  /El Shorta v El Geish";

string[] description = MyString.Split('/');
var result = description.Select(s => s.Trim());
foreach(string s in result)
    Console.WriteLine("|" + s + "|");
```